# R - apply lm on each data frame row

Tags: r, apply, lm

I am trying to apply a simple linear regression between two columns of a data frame, for every row. After some research I feel like I am almost there, but my function still doesn't work. Please take a look:

```
set.seed(1)
DF <- data.frame(A=rnorm(50, 100, 3),
                 B=rnorm(50, 100, 3))

resultlist   <- apply(DF, 1, function(y) lm(y ~ x))
resultcoeffs <- apply(DF, 1, function(y) lm(y ~ x)$coefficients)
```

Any tip on how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just one observation per row.  Note that you get `NA` estimates as there are not enough degrees of freedom.

The idea would be:

```
 mapply(function(x,y) lm(y~x)$coefficients, DF[,1], DF[,2])
```

Or

```
 apply(DF1, 1, function(x) lm(x[2]~x[1])$coefficients)
```

#### EDIT

Suppose, you have many observations per row i.e. `x` and `y` variables span over many columns

```
 mapply(function(x,y) lm(y~x)$coefficients, as.data.frame(t(DFNew[1:3])),
                             as.data.frame(t(DFNew[4:6])))
```

Or

```
 apply(DFNew, 1, function(x) lm(x[4:6]~x[1:3])$coefficients)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(25)
DFNew <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:50,10*6, replace=TRUE), ncol=6))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. The first set of functions was what I was looking for. However, I just realized my data frame has some NA's. And therefore the functions no longer work. Give a try after doing DF[1,1] <- NA

Comment: @ThiagoV.dosSantos  In that case, do you want to exclude the rows that have NAs from doing the lm?

Comment: yes, ideally lm on those rows would return a NA. I tried adding na.action=na.omit, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @ThiagoV.dosSantos  If you want to exclude those rows, try `DF1 <- DF[!rowSums(is.na(DF)),]` and then work on `DF1`.  For the removed rows, you can get the index from `which(!!rowSums(is.na(DF)))`

Comment: That works like a charm. Thanks again @akrun. Try to get some sleep now ;)

Comment: @ThiagoV.dosSantos  Another option is to create a `if` `else` condition. ie. `mapply(function(x,y) if(any(is.na(c(x,y))))  NA else lm(y~x)$coefficients, DF[,1], DF[,2])`