# R: Applying lm on every row of a dataframe using apply family

Tags: r, lm

I have a data frame

```
x y z  
1 4 6  
2 5 7  
3 6 8  
4 7 9  
5 8 10
```

Reproducible example below:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(4,5,6,7,8)
z <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
df
```

I am trying to run a linear regression using lm between lines 1:4 against 5. I am trying to use the apply family here.  I have seen other links  in SO which talk about this , but having a tough time understanding the syntax. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27539033/r-apply-lm-on-each-data-frame-row) was a good link, but I am having a tough time understanding the syntax. This is my attempt at it.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x), lm(x[1,] ~ x[5,])$coefficients)
```

I am not sure what the syntax is  to write apply such that it takes all rows.

I would also be thankful if someone could also show me how to do the same thin but with lm on columns of a dat frame too.

```
df = data.frame(x=c(1:5), y= c(4:8), z=c(6:10))
```

Comment: I think @akrun was the person who answered on the other post.

Comment: This approach is unconventional.  Do you want to run 4 separate regressions, each trying to predict the outcome vector (5, 8, 10)?  In the first regression, the predictor vector is (1, 4, 6).  In the second regression, the predictor is (2, 5, 7)?

Comment: @wibeasley . Yes that is the intent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm defining the data frame differently in two ways: (a) each variable is a column (which is more natural in R), and (b) add a fourth row to the table, so the regression has enough degrees of freedom.  I know I'm answering something slightly different than your question, but I think this scenario will be closer to the real-world one you're facing.

```
library(magrittr)
predictors <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x1, ~x2, ~x3, ~x4,  ~y,  
    1,   2,   3,   4,   5,
    4,   5,   6,   7,   8,
    6,   7,   8,   9,  10,
    7,   3,   8,   4,   8   # Added this row for stability
)
```

The [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) function seem a natural fit to me.

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::select(!!predictors) %>% 
  purrr::map( function(x) coef(lm(df$y ~ x))   ) %>% 
  tibble::enframe(name="predictor", value="coefficients") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    int     = purrr::map_chr(.$coefficients, "(Intercept)"),
    slope   = purrr::map_chr(.$coefficients, "x")
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(predictor, int, slope)
```

1. Line 2: use only the predictor variables (for the looping)
2. Line 3: loop over each predictor (*ie*, `x`), and predict `df$y`. The `coef()` will produce a vector of numerics. (Which may initially seem odd to store two numbers per data.fram cell.)
3. Line 4: convert to a tibble/data.frame for easier manipulation
4. Line 6: within each bivariate set of coefficients, extract the intercept.
5. Line 7: within each bivariate set of coefficients, extract the slope.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question has these problems:

- the `apply` passes one row at a time so x[1, ] is really just `x` -- not wrong but pointless
- x[5, ] is an error since `x` only has one row so one cannot ask for its 5th row
- the `apply` includes the last row which would be regressing that row against itself which seems pointless
- normally one puts the variables in columns and the cases in rows but `df` has it reversed.  With the conventional orientation when one refers to a variable one is referring to a plain vector.  With the orientation of the question `df[i, ]` is a one row data frame rather than a plain vector which is not what we want.
- using the `coef` function is preferred to messing with the internals of the `lm` object as done in the question.
- in a comment to which the poster agreed, @wibeasley stated that `df[i, ]` is the predictor, i.e. independent variable (one for each regression) and `df[5, ]` is the outcome variable, i.e. the dependent variable.  That is the model is 
  `df[5, ] = a + b * df[i, ] + error` 
  with a separate regression for each value of i (except 5).  In that case the variables are listed on the wrong sides of the formula in the code of the question.

**1)** Fixing up these problems we get:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(t(df))
nc <- ncol(DF)
sapply(DF[-nc], function(x)  coef(lm(DF[, nc] ~ x)))
```

giving:

```
            V1 V2 V3 V4
(Intercept)  4  3  2  1
x            1  1  1  1
```

**2)** If you do want to express this in terms of `df` then:

```
nr <- nrow(df)
apply(df[-nr,], 1, function(x) coef(lm(t(df[nr, ]) ~ x)))
```

**3)** If the intent was that `df[5, ]` is the predictor variable then we would not need an `apply` at all and this would do (where `DF` and `nc` are defined above):

```
coef(lm(as.matrix(DF[-nc]) ~ DF[[nc]]))
```

giving:

```
            V1 V2 V3 V4
(Intercept) -4 -3 -2 -1
DF[[nc]]     1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

If you want the predicted value generated by the model then you can use

> fitted(model)